# Kotlin how to copy class property fields in its own member function

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code, I would like to update the properties in `class A`, in c++, I can use something like `this = A()` within the `udpate()` that invokes implicity `operator = ()`

```
data class B(
    var A: Int = 10,
    var B: Long = 20L,
    var C: Double = 200.0
)

data class A(
    var a: Int = 0,
    var b: Long = 0L

) {
    fun badUpdate(input: B) {
        var holder = this@A // It does not work, any better way to update within the member function?
        holder = A(input.A, input.B)
    }

    fun aboriginalUpdate(input:B) {
        a = input.A // It works, but what if I have 30 properties?
        b = input.B
    }

    fun update(input: B) : A {
        return A(input.A, input.B) // Works but not ideal, the return value is not necessary
    }
}


fun main() {
    var data0 = A()
    val data = B(A = 300)
    data0.badUpdate(data) // data0.a does not change (nothing invoked in update0)
    data0 = data0.update(data)
    println("$data0")
}
```

Any better way to update the properties within the `class A`？

Comment: 1) _... = B.A_ does not make sense. B is a Type, not an instance of a class. 2) Why do you create instances of A within A? 3) You update function would contain one line of code: _a = input.A_, and that's it.

Comment: 4) And in the main function you again you a Type where you should use an instance of that type, on line 3 it should be: _data0.update(data)_

Comment: @Slaw: if the OP mixes up things like types and instances, I think it makes no sense to try to come up with an answer about copying 50+ properties.

Comment: @lukas.j thanks for the correction, single property is a bad example, I will update the example

Comment: if A and B share a lot of properties consider making a superclass or interface

Answer (score 0):

I thnk 'apply()' is what you are looking for:

```
data class B(
    var a: Int = 10,
    var b: Long = 20L,
    var c: Double = 200.0
)

data class A(
    var a: Int = 0,
    var b: Long = 0L

) {
    fun goodUpdate(input: B) {
        this.apply {
            a = input.a
            b = input.b
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    var data0 = A()
    val data = B(a = 300)
    data0.goodUpdate(data)
    println("$data0") // A(a=300, b=20)
}
```

but unlike in the example you provided from C, you are not creating a new instance, you are updating properties of the existing one, which I believe you wanted

but you can achieve that even simpler, by reassigning object fields:

```
    fun betterUpdate(input: B) {
        this.a = input.a
        this.b = input.b
    }
```

Comment: It is a solution, but this is pretty much `aboriginalUpdate`. Imaging we have a lot of properties in the class the part `this.a=` becomes pretty annoy. I am looking for something like c++ shallow copy